# CSS Popdown Menu not working in IE7

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

Can anyone tell me why the popdown menu on http://zahnarzt-christmann.de/ is working fine in every browser I tested except in IE7?

Apparently the banner somehow forces the menu to loose the hover state, because if I move the banner down further it works okay.

Now I've tried every combination of z-indexing I could think of, but nothing helps. So can anyone PLEASE tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try make the following changes to `#access ul ul` :

```
position:absolute;
top:60px;
```

You can leave the `z-index` set as it is. It works for me in IE with with the compatibility mode targeted on version 7.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried every combination of position and z-index, but apparently not.